# Ошибка в определение длины строки переменной массива структуры.Подскажите пожалуйста

Tags: c++, структуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я ищу длину строки переменной массива структуры.

```
struct Dannie{ 
   int number; 
   string name;
   void Input();
};         

void Dannie::Input()
{ 
   int k; 
   cin>>k;
   Dannie a[k]={};
   int i;
   char a5=a[i].name.length();
}
```

Выдает ошибку(

```
test.cpp:78:14: error: invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript
   char a5=a[i].name.length();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100152/discussion-on-question-by-leila-------).